# Visual Basic Read from Keyboard

Tags: vb.net, keyboard

I am trying to implement a simple calculation to output Total Price using Visual Basic.NET

I want to read Original Price and Shipping Weight then use it in the calculation. The problem is, 
When I enter any values, both variables will return only first digit

For example, if enter 23 it will return 2

```
    Dim originalPrice As Double
    Dim commissionPrice As Double
    Dim shippingWeight As Double
    Dim totalPrice As Double   

    Console.Write("Enter Original Price: ")
    originalPrice = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine(originalPrice))

    Console.Write("Enter Shipping Weight: ")
    shippingWeight = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine(shippingWeight))   
    shippingWeight = shippingWeight * 7

    If (originalPrice + shippingWeight >= 200) Then
        commissionPrice = (originalPrice + shippingWeight) * 0.03
    Else
        commissionPrice = 5
    End If

    totalPrice = commissionPrice + originalPrice + shippingWeight

    Console.WriteLine(originalPrice)
    Console.WriteLine(commissionPrice)
    Console.WriteLine(shippingWeight)       
    Console.WriteLine(totalPrice)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your problem is that you are passing the variable to the Console.read()

In this way should work.

```
    Dim originalPrice As Double
    Dim commissionPrice As Double
    Dim shippingWeight As Double
    Dim totalPrice As Double

    Console.Write("Enter Original Price: ")
    originalPrice = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine())

    Console.Write("Enter Shipping Weight: ")
    shippingWeight = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine())
    shippingWeight = shippingWeight * 7

    If (originalPrice + shippingWeight >= 200) Then
        commissionPrice = (originalPrice + shippingWeight) * 0.03
    Else
        commissionPrice = 5
    End If

    totalPrice = commissionPrice + originalPrice + shippingWeight

    Console.WriteLine(originalPrice)
    Console.WriteLine(commissionPrice)
    Console.WriteLine(shippingWeight)
    Console.WriteLine(totalPrice)

    Console.Read()
```

Comment: Beat me to it.  `Console.ReadLine(index)` returns the Char at the passed index.

Comment: I tried  ` Console.Read(a)` gives compilation error

Comment: @AbdullaDlshad - Why are you using `Console.Read(a)`? The code above works fine.  All you have to do to the code in your question is remove the parameters to `Console.ReadLine()`.

Comment: @Comintern I did not use `Console.Read(a)` I  just did not know that using parameters will return Char.
Anyways, the code works fine thank you very much